# How can I select the MySQL rows on the based on ID? Is there any affect on performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a List and want to select rows by their ID. are this affect the queries performance and better alternate to do that.

Comment: Every query affects performance. If you have an alternative of not performing query - then don't perform it.

Comment: my means to write a queries who is better then this one [mine]

Comment: @Moby: your one? You did not post any query in your question.

Comment: write a queries  means write another queries instead of this one i posted here

Comment: @Moby: may be I'm blind, but you *haven't posted any query*

Comment: i putted them in title unproperly by "select the MySQL rows on the based on ID

Comment: @Moby: I'm sorry but I cannot get you. It is not a mysql query. Anyway, I and 2 other guys have given answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list and do the following kind of query :

```
select * from your_table where id = 123
select * from your_table where id = 345
select * from your_table where id = 679
```

for each one of the items of your list, you'll end up doing a lot of queries -- which, as you can guess, is not that good for performances.

An idea might be to group those queries, like this :

```
select * from your_table where id in (123, 345, 679)
```

To do less queries : only one here, instead of three.

This means a bit more logic in your code, to get the results from the database, of course ; but it will generally help, when it comes to performances.

Note though : you should not use too much ids in a single `in()` clause -- which means you might end up doing several queries -- each one working on several ids.

Comment: Never, **NEVER** say to newbies that "less queries means better performance" (in this case it is of course true, but after such hints newbies make really terrible monsters instead of 2 simple queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

This query will be enough performant as well as you have an index that covers `id` in its left-most part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of rows IDs, you just do following select:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This is the fastest way to fetch rows basing on their IDs.